# Stripe and WordPress - verify-identity-documents modal

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use Stripe's verify-identity-documents with the modal route within a WordPress install. I'm not sure where I would place the below code to create a Verification Session?

Should this be its own plugin?
I have already downloaded and added strip as a new plugin, but when I call the modal up nothing happens and I get a 404 on the fetch('/create-verification-session'.

I'm trying to follow the instruction here https://stripe.com/docs/identity/verify-identity-documents but this needs to be placed within a wordpress theme / setup.

```
use Stripe\Stripe;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_51IUfiAKBpqLAYasy1QzBG7eKEFVnR1TxC9wwQZ48Eq1tHT5hRW11tA2OmH004vg8xt0i'

);

// In the route handler for /create-verification-session:
// Authenticate your user

// Create the session
$verification_session = $stripe->identity->verificationSessions->create
([
  'type
' => 'document',
  'metadata
' => [
    'user_id' => '{{USER_ID}}',
  ],
]);

// Return only the client secret to the frontend.
$client_secret = $verification_session->client_secret;
```

Comment: First, avoid revealing your Stripe secret key (sk_test_xxx) here. It's your Stripe Account credential and anyone can use it to send requests on behalf of you.

Comment: And for your question, have you implemented the route handler for "/create-verification-session"? Your code seems to have it commented out and doesn't look like a handler function. This is more of a route configuration on Wordpress before calling any Stripe API

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php site to find out how to use it.

It's really straight-forward.

Comment: Thanks, had a look through but it’s beyond me…